# regex: split by parentheses ignore nested parentheses inside quotes

Tags: java, regex

My program parses SQL VALUES multi-row string into single-row string array.

Typical input string looks like:

```
(11,'-1','Service A (nested parentheses)','en') (22,'-2','Service B (nested parentheses)','en')
```

Desired output:

- group 1: `11,'-1','Service A (nested parentheses)','en'`
- group 2: `22,'-2','Service B (nested parentheses)','en'`

I have tried following regexp, with partial luck only:

```
\(('.*?'|.*?)\)
```

What would be the right way to handle this in regexp?

EDIT:

- Target platform is Java 6/7
- There is no need in replacing the parentheses with new line - only to capture the groups

Comment: What language? PCRE supports recursive regular expressions, which can do this. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html

Comment: If you're [using lua...](http://codepad.org/8IzarHjG)

Comment: @Barmar: you don't need recursion since parenthesis inside quotes are ignored. With `\((?>'[^']*'|[^')]++)*\)` you can match an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** After your comment about smilies, I'll suggest an alternative approach:

```
(?<=\()(?:'[^']*'|[,\s]+|\d+)+(?=\))
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iR9qS9). This assumes that your tokens are either strings delimited by single quotes, or digits. Is that correct?

**Original Answer**

With one potential level of nesting, this will work in most regex flavors, including Java:

```
(?<=\()(?:[^()]+|\([^)]+\))+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/cU8rC7)

**How does it work?**

1. The lookbehind asserts that the previous character is an opening parenthesis `(`
2. The non-capturing group with the `+` quantifier matches one or more of: (i) any number of characters that are not opening or closing parentheses, OR `|` (ii) full `(parenthesized expressions)`

If you want to make sure that the container is balanced, add a lookahead at the end:

```
(?<=\()(?:[^()]+|\([^)]+\))+(?=\))
```

Comment: This is an impressive regexp! It seams to be smile-unfriendly: ('Android KitKat(4.4) Devices', ':)',  '&:*(' , 'Slendrina:The Cellar (Free)')

Comment: @danm See new regex at the top of my answer, let me know if this suits your needs or if something is missing. :)

Comment: @danm After the fix, did this solve your problem? Asking because I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an answer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Comment: Great regex, I was about to give up until I found this.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern.compile("\\(((?:'[^']*'|[^'\\(\\)]+)+)\\)");
```

[RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/ypkf0) click the `Java` link.

The meat of the regex is `'[^']*'|[^'\(\)]` - any series of any characters surrounded by single quotations OR any string of characters excluding single quotes and round brackets.  This avoids having to use look arounds, although the look around suggested by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) may in fact be more efficient (I am not particularly familiar with the performance aspect of look arounds in Java).

Answer (score 0):

With caveats:

```
/\(.*\)/\1/
```

Will remove the surrounding parenthesis, and

```
/\) \(/\r/g
```

Will put in newlines as in your example

Caveats:

- This regex is in a generalized form, since you didn't specify which regex implementation
- This only works if the input closely matches your example