# Python regexp match across lines

Tags: python, regex

I have a bibtex file formatted like this:

```
@inproceedings{baz,
    AUTHOR={{Baz}, {S}. and Bar, {G}. and
      Foo, {M}},
    year={2013}
}
```

I have managed to capture a single entry (the entire text shown above), but I want a regex in Python that matches everything inside the `AUTHOR={}` brackets (across the newline). How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Did you try anything?...Post your code if so..

Comment: @cmeeren: Are you not satisfied with the answer you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex that checks for 1 level of nested curly braces:

```
(?ims)author\s*=\s*[{"]((?:[^{}]+?|{[^}]+?})+?)[}"]
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX3lG3/5)

[Sample code on IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ilpqR1):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?ims)author\s*=\s*[{"]((?:[^{}]+?|{[^}]+?})+?)[}"]')
test_str = "@inproceedings{baz,\n    AUTHOR = {{Baz}, {S}. and Bar, {G}. and\n      Foo, {M}},\n    year={2013}\n}\n@inproceedings{baz,\n    AUTHOR={{%Baz%}, {S!}. and Bar, {^G^}. and\n      Foo, {<M>}},\n    year={2013}\n}\n"
print [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, so I'll accept it. Unfortunately it didn't solve my real problem, because the regex must allow more varied formatting than I wrote in my question. Based on your answer and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23840317/2978652), I made [this](https://regex101.com/r/vX3lG3/5), using a capture group to retrieve the desired part instead of lookahead/lookbehind.

Comment: Great, if you showed the other examples, it would be easier to come up with a working approach. Certainly, a variable width look-behind is not possible here. I also think you may use `finditer` here since it is easier to grab capture group text with this method. Please consider upvoting my answer if you found it (?:useful|helpful). :)

Comment: Briefly - how is it easier with `finditer`?

Comment: Well, maybe this is a matter of taste, but `[x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]` is my preferred way of accessing captured groups.

Answer (score 2):

```
re.compile(r"AUTHOR={([\sA-Za-z{},\.]+)},$", re.MULTILINE)
```